# I am getting error when trying to run next build in next.js app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, vercel

I don't understand when I test `npm run dev` it works just fine , but when I run `npm run build` i get this error .I use my API logic directly in `getStaticProps / getStaticPath`

How can i solve this error to deploy my app to vercel?

```
> Build error occurred
FetchError: invalid json response body at https://elgendy1986.vercel.app/api/products reason: Unexpected 
token T in JSON at position 0
    at D:\Web-Design-Development\Real Work\Elgendy-E-Commerce\node_modules\node-fetch\lib\index.js:272:32    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:94:5)
    at async getStaticPaths (D:\Web-Design-Development\Real Work\Elgendy-E-Commerce\.next\server\pages\products\[slug].js:344:16)
    at async buildStaticPaths (D:\Web-Design-Development\Real Work\Elgendy-E-Commerce\node_modules\next\dist\build\utils.js:16:80)
    at async D:\Web-Design-Development\Real Work\Elgendy-E-Commerce\node_modules\next\dist\build\utils.js:26:622
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (D:\Web-Design-Development\Real Work\Elgendy-E-Commerce\node_modules\next\dist\telemetry\trace\trace.js:6:584) {
  type: 'invalid-json'
}
```

this is My /pages/products/index.js

```
import Head from "next/head";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import Breadcrumb from "../../components/helpers/Breadcrumb";
import Filters from "../../components/product/Filters";
import Product_List from "../../components/product/Product_List";
import Sort from "../../components/product/Sort";
const index = ({ products }) => {
  const { pathname } = useRouter();
  const path = pathname.split("/").slice(1);
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Elgendy E-Commerce | Our Products</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
        <meta name="author" content="Amr Elgendy" />
        <meta name="description" content="e-commerce website" />
      </Head>
      <Breadcrumb path={path} />
      <main className="grid gap-y-14 md:grid-cols-200-1fr min-h-screen mt-20 mb-10">
        <Filters />
        <div className="">
          <Sort />
          <Product_List products={products} />
        </div>
      </main>
    </>
  );
};
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const res = await fetch(`${process.env.URL}/api/products`);
  const data = await res.json();
  
  return {
    props: {
      products: data,
    },
  };
}
export default index;
```

this is my /pages/products/[slug].js

```
import React from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import Link from "next/link";
import Breadcrumb from "../../components/helpers/Breadcrumb";
import Star from "../../components/product/Star";
import { formatPrice } from "../../components/utils/constants";
import ProductImages from "../../components/product/ProductImages";
import AddToCart from "../../components/cart/AddToCart";
import Head from "next/head";

const ProductDetails = ({ product }) => {
  const { pathname, query } = useRouter();
  const path = [pathname.split("/")[1], query.slug];

  const {
    _id: SKU,
    name,
    brand,
    description,
    images,
    rating,
    numReviews,
    price,
    quantity,
  } = product;

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>{name}</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
        <meta name="author" content="Amr Elgendy" />
        <meta name="description" content="e-commerce website" />
      </Head>
      <section className="min-h-page">
        <Breadcrumb path={path} />
        <div className="px-5 py-12">
          <Link href="/products">
            <a className="capitalize py-1 px-3 bg-secondary text-white rounded hover:bg-third transition-all duration-300">
              back to products
            </a>
          </Link>
          <div className="grid lg:grid-cols-2 items-center  gap-8 mt-8">
            <ProductImages images={images} />
            <section className="content">
              <h2 className="text-3xl font-semibold mb-4">{name}</h2>
              <Star rating={rating} reviews={numReviews} />
              <h5 className="text-secondary mb-4 text-lg">
                {formatPrice(price)}
              </h5>
              <p className="leading-loose text-p mb-4">{description}</p>
              <p className={quantity === 0 ? "capitalize w-72 grid grid-cols-125-1fr mb-4 text-red-600" : "capitalize w-72 grid grid-cols-125-1fr mb-4 text-secondary"}>
                <span className="font-bold text-black">Available : </span>
                {quantity > 0 ? "In stock" : "out of stock"}
              </p>
              <p className="capitalize text-xs sm:text-base grid grid-cols-125-1fr mb-4">
                <span className="font-bold text-base">SKU :</span>
                {SKU}
              </p>
              <p className="capitalize w-72 grid grid-cols-125-1fr mb-4">
                <span className="font-bold">Brand :</span>
                {brand}
              </p>
              <hr />
              {quantity > 0 && <AddToCart product={product} />}
            </section>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </>
  );
};

export async function getStaticProps({ params: { slug } }) {
  const res = await fetch(`${process.env.URL}/api/products/${slug}`);
  const data = await res.json();

  return {
    props: { product: data },
  };
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const res = await fetch(`${process.env.URL}/api/products`);
  const data = await res.json();

  const paths = data.map((product) => ({ params: { slug: product.slug } }));

  return {
    paths,
    fallback: false,
  };
}

export default ProductDetails;
```

this is my next.config.js

```
const { PHASE_DEVELOPMENT_SERVER } = require('next/constants');

module.exports = (phase) => {
  if (phase === PHASE_DEVELOPMENT_SERVER) {
    return {
      env: {
        jwt_secret: 'abc123',
        URL: 'http://localhost:3000',
      },
    };
  } else {
    return {
      env: {
        jwt_secret: 'abc123',
        URL: 'https://elgendy1986.vercel.app',
      },
    };
  }
};
```

Comment: Please remove the gibberish and do what the editor says

Comment: since the error is inside `api/products` you should post also that page code